# How can i get two specific values from a String using useDelimeter in java?

Tags: java

I am trying to get the two player values from "line" String and insert them into player1 and player2, using regular expression.

```
   try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {

        String line;
        String player1;
        String player2;

        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(line);

            input.useDelimiter("(.* [a-z] )|\\sby ");

            if(line.toLowerCase().contains("kill")) {
                kill +=  1;

                //i would like to set the player1 and player2 here
            }                   
        }      
    }
```

Fragment of my file(.txt):

```
 13:37 Kill: 3 4 7: Oootsimo killed Dono da Bola by MOD_ROCKET_SPLASH
 13:37 Item: 5 weapon_rocketlauncher
 13:39 Item: 6 weapon_rocketlauncher
 13:40 Item: 7 ammo_rockets
 13:41 Item: 6 weapon_rocketlauncher
 13:41 Item: 4 weapon_rocketlauncher
 13:43 Kill: 2 5 6: Isgalamido killed Assasinu Credi by MOD_ROCKET
 13:45 Kill: 1022 7 22: <world> killed Mal by MOD_TRIGGER_HURT
 13:46 Kill: 4 3 7: Dono da Bola killed Oootsimo by MOD_ROCKET_SPLASH
 13:46 Kill: 6 2 6: Zeh killed Isgalamido by MOD_ROCKET
```

Comment: Hi Eros, please show your attempt first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know all of your requirements, but try using Regexp:

```
@Test
public void test()
{
    String string = "13:46 Kill: 6 2 6: Zeh killed Isgalamido by MOD_ROCKET";
    String regexp = "\\d+:\\d+ .*?([A-Za-z0-9]+) killed ([A-Za-z0-9]+).*?";
    String player1 = null;
    String player2 = null;

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regexp);

    Matcher m = p.matcher(string);

    if (m.find())
    {
        player1 = m.group(1);
        player2 = m.group(2);
    }

    assertEquals("Zeh", player1);
    assertEquals("Isgalamido", player2);
}
```

Explanation: 
\d+ - A digit, one or more times

.* - Any character, any number of times. the '?' means 'non greedy', so characters matching the following expression won't be overaken

([A-Za-z0-9]+) - character ranges inside the '[]', one or more times, captured

I'll edit my answer again once I can confirm this is what you meant